# Localhost on Docker Has "conflicting server name" Problem

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to launch a docker image with localhost. The code is open sourced and here:

https://github.com/Helium-MVC/Boilerplate

When I run `docker-compose up`, I get the following:

```
helium_nginx | 2018/12/11 07:43:31 [warn] 1#1: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
helium_nginx | nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

Now my docker site.conf only has 1 vhost:

```
server {
    #The port to listen on. SSL would listen on 443
    listen 80 default_server;

    #The name/alias the server listens for when deciding to use this configuration
    server_name  localhost _;

    #Where the lo files are being written too
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    #Location of our site
    location / {
            #The root of the site is in public_html
        root    /code/site/public_html/;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        #important for pretty url and routing
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?rt=$uri&$args;
    }                                                                 
}
```

With it set in the yml like so:

```
web:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: "helium_nginx"
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
      - ./nginx_custom_settings.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx_custom_settings.conf
    links: ['php']
```

What is weird is that is if I change the `server_name` to something like www.example.com and place that name in my `/etc/hosts` file, **it works**! Otherwise using localhost I get only the **nginx default page**. What can be wrong?

Comment: Maybe your nginx image has `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file (or similar) which conflicts with your `site.conf`?

Comment: Is there a spot that the default.conf is being loaded where I am not setting it? Per the github code, I never incude or modify the default.conf @Ivan Shatsky

Comment: can you provide nginx_custom_settings.conf code?

Comment: @myxaxa Its a single line to increase the post size for uploads: client_max_body_size 100m;

Comment: `default.conf` comes with default nginx configuration and loaded from `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` via `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

To provide an answer, I had to change the default nginx configuration. In my YML I added:

```
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: "helium_nginx"
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./:/code
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    additionnx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

The addittion was the `- ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

The nginx.conf being copied was this:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf;
}
```

What I changed was instead of having  include `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` that would load all configuration, I loaded just the one I wanted,  include `/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf;`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the `nginx` image in docker, which has a `default.conf` file with `server_name localhost` and listening port 80. I simply replace that file and get this resolved.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx: 
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/https_reverse_proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/https_reverse_proxy.conf
      - ./tmp/http_reverse_proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

and http_reverse_proxy.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name localhost;

  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```